# Resize a table cell using css resize:both; not working with table

Tags: html, css

Resize a table cell using css {resize:both;} not working with table

I need to resize table and its cell, resize able using css ,
 css {resize:both;} is working in div but not in table tags

```
<table border="1" style="resize:both;">
<tr>
<td>hi table</td>
<td>hi div</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>hi table</td>
<td>hi div</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>hi table</td>
<td>hi div</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

can any body help

Comment: Sigh why was such a standard feature like resizable columns that have been super simple to do in desktop apps for 15+ years not added to css3/html5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that resize: is not applicable to tables.

```
table {
    border:2px solid;
    padding:10px 40px; 
    width:300px;
    resize:both;
    overflow:auto;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_/q4qwp/

But you can wrap the table in a div and set the resize: to the div instead, but you cannot shrink the table even with % width values.

http://jsfiddle.net/q4qwp/3/

Comment: How to resize the cell? can you please help

Comment: You can't resize the table with this method. You'll have to resort to javascript.

Comment: Links doesn't exist anymore

Comment: @titusfx link restored.

Comment: Is there anyway to move the resizer to take the entire border ?  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_resize . This seems to be the same.

Answer (score 9):

To cover Chrome and Safari, use

```
th, td { resize: both; overflow: auto; }
```

Do not set initial width on the table as a whole. You can set the widths of cells or columns, though.

To cover Firefox as well, I’m afraid you would need to wrap the content of each cell on a `div` with a class and add the corresponding class selector to the rule above. And this would introduce two resize handles on Chrome and Safari in each cell... so maybe you should use

```
<td><div class=cell>...</div></td>
```

for every cell and the CSS rule

```
.cell { resize: both; overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

(without making `td` elements resizable).

This way, all cells are resizable, so the table as a whole is indirectly resizable (as long as you do not set its width and height).

In principle, `resize` applies to all elements with `overflow` property other than `visible`. In practice, it works in a much more limited way, and differently in different browsers.

Comment: i love ur first answer : th, td { resize: both; overflow: auto; } for chrome and safari. thank you

Answer (score 2):

To resize tables and table columns you have to use Javascript. There are several jQuery plugins out there doing so, for example `colResizable`, which allows you to drag column anchors manually.

Here is a small snippet of code:

```
$("#tabe").colResizable({});
```

you can find more examples on: http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/
or you can try this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/euka4rm3/

Answer (score 1):

you can use styles of the outer div to change position of the table. For example

```
<div style="resize:both">
    <table id="sample table"></table>
</div>
```